# Unity says "error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a cross board game using Unity based on a tutorial. This problem occurs when I add a jump animation.
All my code is from that tutorial and no changes have been made except for one value.

I know which line of code is wrong but I don't know why and I don't know how to fix it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Playermovement : MonoBehaviour
{
  private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float jumpAmount = 1;

    bool isGrounded;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundlayer;
    public Animator anim;
    public float overlap = 0.5f;
   

    void Start()
    {

        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (isGrounded)
            {
                Jump();
            }
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, overlap, groundlayer);
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up *5* jumpAmount, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    if(isGrounded)
        {
            anim.SetBool("Jump",false);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("Jump", true);
        }
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with this, please?
Thank you in advance to those who answered!

> Assets\Script\Playermovement.cs(52,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

This is the error message I received. I know it tells me the error occurred on the first character of line 52 (which is the last line), but other than that I don't know anything because there is only one curly bracket on that line.

Comment: Are `if(isGrounded)` and the lines that follow in a function?

Comment: Check the curly brackets: probably you omitted a closing bracket.

Comment: Please pay attention to the tags you select. You can't just press a single letter and then `Enter`, that will very likely select the wrong tags. Like the C language tag instead of C#.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `if (isGrounded)` statement. The `if/else` statement needs to be in a `method/function`, and can't work without being in one.

Comment: Thank you! I try to put the statment in to a method, the code is working now.

Comment: No problem, if your question has been answered, please mark the answer as 'accepted'.